# Edit number reference in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I have a problem with the style of the references. I need to eliminate the point after the number, like this:

> 2 Programmer’s Manual for ANSYS [Текст]. – М.: SAS IP, Inc., 2007. – 312 с.

Far now, I wrote this

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document} 
\begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of references      
\bibitem{CommandReference} ANSYS Mechanical APDL Command Reference [Текст]. – М.: SAS IP, Inc., 2010. – 1934 с.
\bibitem{ProgrammersManual} Programmer’s Manual for ANSYS [Текст]. – М.: SAS IP, Inc., 2007. – 312 с.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the next:

> 2. Programmer’s Manual for ANSYS [Текст]. – М.: SAS IP, Inc., 2007. – 312 с.

Comment: The format of the (label) number in your bibliography can either be controlled by your document class or by a bibliography-related package you use. The solution will depend on your document and bibliography setup. We can only give a useful answer if you can show us a short example document that reproduces the status quo with as little irrelevant code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) while still being fully compilable and ideally self-contained (the code posted in the question currently does not meet those criteria because it has no `\documentclass`)

Comment: @moewe I made the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you @SulinW.